# How to skip over a method call inside that is inside the method being unit tested

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a method call that I am unit testing. Inside that method call it makes a call to a method that is going to throw an error because it is trying to talk to a device that will not be available when the unit test is running. Is there a way to avoid that internal method call from being called?

Environment: C# Visual Studio 2010 unit testing within IDE

Answer (score 5):

If you're unit testing a class with external dependencies then you must isolate the external dependancies using an interface which is injected in.

```
interface IDevice
{
    void Run();
}

interface IDeviceOperator
{
    void Operate();
}

class DeviceOperator : IDeviceOperator 
{
    private readonly IDevice _device;

    public DeviceOperator(IDevice device)
    {
        _device = device;
    }

    public void Operate()
    {
        _device.Run();

        // test other stuff here
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class DeviceOperatorTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Test_DeviceOperator_Operate()
    {
        IDevice device = A.Fake<IDevice>(); // Using FakeItEasy 3rd party mocking framework syntax
        DeviceOperator deviceOperator = new DeviceOperator(device);

        deviceOperator.Operate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When doing unit testing you have to create mocks or stubs for all your external dependencies. A framework that could help you with that is [Moq](https://code.google.com/p/moq/) (it is plenty of mock frameworks if you want to explore).

These mock or stubs are just facades providing necessary interactions and data to pass your tests.

We may be able to help you more if you provide more details about that *unavailable device*.

Comment: There's a dependency in the method he is trying to unit test.  He needs to structure his code so that he can resolve that dependency by injection or some other means if he plans to make it testable.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a better way, but once or twice I've been in this situation where a method calls another, complicated method, and put an optional parameter at the end of the method you're testing like

```
public void DoSomething(int number, bool skipMethod= false)
{
    if(!skipMethod)
        MethodThatWillBreak();
{
```

So that in the normal course of running, it'll be fine, but in your unit test you can do

```
DoSomething(2,true);
```

But really, it suggests that you need to do some refactoring of your code, because your unit test should only be hitting one "unit". If you can test the method without calling the `MethodThatWillBreak` then what is it doing there in the first place.

Comment: Semantics are slightly off here.  Should rename callMethod to skipMethod as you have it written.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052) book by Michael Feathers - it have a lot of suggestions on dealing with code that does not have unit test yet.

Possible approaches covered in the book:

- extract dependency in interface - ideal approach (see jamespconnor's answer)
- use flag to bypass call (see Colm Prunty's answer)
- extract that call into virtual method and override in derived class used in unit test
- pass delegate (may be less impact than full interface/derivation)

Sample for deriving from the class:

```
public class WithComplexDependency
{
   public void DoSomething()
   {
     // Extract original code into a virtual protected method
     // dependency.MethodThatWillBreak();
     CallMethodThatWillBreak();
   }

   virtual protected void CallMethodThatWillBreak()
   {
      dependency.MethodThatWillBreak();
   }
}
```

in test code derive from the class and provide own implementation:

```
public class WithMockComplexDependency : WithComplexDependency
{
   // may also need to add constructor to call original one.

   override protected void CallMethodThatWillBreak()
   {
      // do whatever is needed for your test
   }
}

...
WithComplexDependency testObject = new WithMockComplexDependency();
testObject.DoSomething(); // now does not call dependency.MethodThatWillBreak()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

To unit test correctly you should decouple the comunication with the device  from the class you want to test! Abstract the partetalking to the device in another class implementing an interface, inject the communication class in the ctor of the object under test, now you can inject a mock implementation from outside and avoid the errore,the mmock implementation can also log call made to it or respond in a predefined way easing test.
Read a out dependency injection and inversion of control

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would extract external dependencies from the class you're testing and will swap them with fake ones in your unit test. You would isolate them and test the part that you're interested in. I recommend that you look into Inversion of Control as well as one of the many Mocking Frameworks ([Moq](https://code.google.com/p/moq/), [Rhino Mocks](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-mocks) etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to SKIP the external. Instead you want to isolate the external dependencies such as accessing external devices. There are many ways to do this
a. You can use a third part isolation framework such as Moq, or RhinoMock, etc
b. You can use Moles framework (since you are using VS2010) - replace a .NET method with a delegate
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/
c. Paid isolation frameworks such as TypeMock.
d. Or simply hand written fake implementation which uses in interface and your test uses the Fake implementation.